# saving baby grass which is starting to wash away in the rain

Tags: grass, seedlings, germination, rain

12 days after planting Kentucky Bluegrass, I just had a lot of rain.
Many spots had already germinated such that the green grassy shoot is about
1/4 inch long, with roots just barely into the soil, but that baby grass is now
mostly lying flat/sideways (somewhat due to the heavy rain, and somewhat due
to my placing a heavy tarp on this area to shelter it for part of the rain).

Should I now topdress these uprooted seedlings with soil (like 1/4 inch) to
help them reestablish roots?  Or, will the topdressing block light and
therefore wind up killing my already-sprouted grass?

A little more rain is expected today and tomorrow which I believe would be
perfect for normal watering.  But, even with normal watering, I worry about
this sideways baby grass lifting and floating away.  Should I topdress,
do nothing, put the tarp back down, or what?

Answer (score 2):

Depending how much washed away, reseed and cover with something like this and don't forget to water https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-ft-x-112-5-ft-Single-Net-Seed-Germination-and-Erosion-Control-Blanket-87363/305429568?MERCH=REC-_-searchViewed-_-NA-_-305429568-_-N&